# Is a runner card turned facedown still itself?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Test Run](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02047) reads:

> Search your stack or heap for a program. Install that program,
>   ignoring all costs. Shuffle your stack if you searched it. When this
>   turn ends, add the program to the top of your stack if it is still
>   installed.

[Harbinger](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09034) reads:

> When Harbinger is trashed, install it facedown instead of adding it to your heap.

Suppose I use Test Run to bring a Harbinger out of my Heap, then trash Harbinger so that it becomes installed face down. Does Test Run put it on my deck at the end of my turn, or does it stay installed face down?

[image: Test Run][image: Harbinger]

Comment: My first instinct is that it would stay in play, but I do not know for certain so will not post an answer. As Harbinger is not yet actually been released it may be hard to find a specific ruling for this case. I would tweet Lucas and ask for a rules verification. This will accomplish two things. 1) You will get your answer. 2) It will ensure this type of interaction is brought to his attention and likely get put in the next FAQ.

Comment: Good idea. I just did so. I suppose this is actually a more general question about how to treat facedown installed cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facedown cards are no longer the same card they were before being turned facedown. In this example, Test Run's "if it is still installed" fails to trigger, and the cards stays where it is.

Based on Project ANCUR's answer to the [question on twitter](https://twitter.com/andrewvan/status/647100448621522945), which was favorited by Lukas (and therefore fairly authoritative, I suppose):

> No. By being turned face down, it is no longer the previous instance
>   of Harbinger that Test Run has a reference to (it's not an instance of
>   Harbinger at all, just an installed facedown runner card)